# run pyspark locally with pycharm

Tags: pyspark

I wrote the following very simple python script with my Pycharm IDE

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.types import LongType, FloatType,IntegerType,StringType,DoubleType
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from  pyspark.sql.functions import abs
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext

spark = SparkSession.builder.config("requiredconfig").appName("SparkSran").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext
```

when I click on run on my IDE or run the following command

```
spark-submit --py-files   /home/user/PycharmProjects/helloSparkWorld/test.py
I get

/usr/lib/spark/bin/spark-class: line 71: /usr/local/java/jdk10.0.1/bin/java: No such file or directory
```

my JAVA_HOME and SPARK_HOME are set as follows
echo `$SPARK_HOME` gives `/usr/lib/spark`
and 
echo `$JAVA_HOME` gives

```
/usr/local/java/jdk10.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just do a `pip install pyspark` in your environment that you are using with your pycharm installation to run python programs. You can run your pyspark `.py` files as `python filename.py` itself, if you're running it locally.

Basically just provide your `pip` or python interpreter with the pyspark pip package and you'll be able to run it via pycharm using the same interpreter.